# Python print the parent element without printing the child element text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup.  I want to print the text with parent element without getting printing the child element.

```
<li class="list-item p-a-0"><b class="inline">First Name:</b> James </li>
```

Expected Output:

```
James
```

this is my code:

```
for item in soup2.findAll('div',{'class':'box-body light-b'}):
    sub_items = item.findAll('li')
    for sub_item in sub_items:
        print(sub_item)
```

li and b element,

I just want to print li element without printing the b element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two ways you can do it

```
# 1
for item in soup2.findAll("div", {"class": "box-body light-b"}):
    sub_items = item.findAll("li")
    for sub_item in sub_items:
        print(list(sub_item.strings)[-1]) # prints James
# 2
for item in soup2.findAll("div", {"class": "box-body light-b"}):
    sub_items = item.findAll("li")
    for sub_item in sub_items:
        for child in sub_item.findAll("b"):
            child.decompose() # removes the b tag
        print(sub_item.text)
```

Comment: Hi THANK YOU!!! You are legend im thinking about this for a week haha. Gladly you commented....!!! Thanks anyway